# Find records that were created X days ago

Tags: postgresql

I want to get all the `paid_account` records that were created exactly 11 days ago. Here's what I have now:

```
SELECT *
  FROM paid_account
 WHERE date_trunc('day', created_at) = date_trunc('day', date ?)

-- The ? gets replaced with today's date in the user's timezone.
```

This works but it seems like there must be a simpler way to do it. Is there a better way?

Comment: What about `created_at::date = (current_date - 11)`?

Comment: That worked. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can substract 11 from [`current_date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) and compare it with `created_at` casted to date:

```
created_at::date = (current_date - 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you'd subtract a value of type interval from either a value of type date or a value of type timestamp. PostgreSQL supports standard SQL in this case.

Since columns named "created_at" are usually timestamps, you can do something like this.

```
select *
from paid_account
where cast(created_at as date) = current_date - interval '11' day;
```

But the WHERE clause isn't sargable.  (PostgreSQL-specific syntax, as `created_at::date` isn't sargable, either.) If you look at the execution plan, you'll find that it invariably uses a sequential scan.

Creating an index on "created_at" alone won't help. You need an index on the expression `date(created_at)` to get good performance.

```
create index on paid_account (date(created_at));
```